# angularJS fullstack :: assertionError: expected open to have been called with arguments matching

Tags: angularjs, angular-fullstack, karma-mocha

In my controller there is a function ......

```
function showDesktopPreview() {
      var self = this;
      this.$uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'app/templates/modals/desktopPreview/template.desktopPreview.html',
        controller: 'TemplateDesktopPreviewModalController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        size: 'xl',
        resolve: {
          previewUrl: function previewUrl() {
            return self.getFrameUrl();
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Now I write down the Karma test script as below ....

```
describe('When calling the showDesktopPreview function', () => {
      let modalOptions;
      let previewUrl;
      beforeEach(() => {
        TemplatesCreateController = createController();
        //previewUrl = TemplatesCreateController.getFrameUrl();
        modalOptions = {
          templateUrl: 'app/templates/modals/desktopPreview/template.desktopPreview.html',
          controller: 'TemplateDesktopPreviewModalController',
          controllerAs: 'vm',
          size: 'x1',
          resolve: {
            previewUrl: (value) => {
              return value() === TemplatesCreateController.previewUrl();
            }
          }
        };
        console.log(modalOptions.resolve.previewUrl);
        TemplatesCreateController.showDesktopPreview();
      });
      it('should instantiate the $uibModal service ', () => {
   expect(TemplatesCreateController.$uibModal).to.not.be.an('undefined');
      });
      it('should call $uibModal.open with correct params', () => {
        scope.$apply();
        expect(TemplatesCreateController.$uibModal.open).to.have
        .been.called
        .and.be.calledWithMatch({modalOptions});
      });
  });
```

This is giving error as

**assertionError: expected open to have been called with arguments matching**

Please help me to resolve this issue.